# Restlet obtaining Application

Tags: java, restlet-2.0

In Restlet 2.3 what is the recommended way of obtaining an `Application`?

The [docs](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.2/jse/api/org/restlet/Application.html) suggest there is a static method `Application.getCurrent()` that implies that it is possible to obtain the executing `Application`. However, this requires the call to be made from the executing `Application`.

Say I had several applications and they are all running:

```
public class ApplicationA extends Application {...}

public class ApplicationB extends Application {...}
```

Is it possible to obtain `Application` for `ApplicationA` from `ApplicationB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the way you configured your Restlet "application" but since you define your routing based on application instances, you could inject one into other one, as described below:

```
Component c = new Component();
(...)

MyApplication1 app1 = new MyApplication1();
c.getDefaultHost().attach("/app1", app1);

MyApplication1 app2 = new MyApplication2(app1);
c.getDefaultHost().attach("/app1", app2);

(...)
```

You can notice that you can also introspect your application at runtime. The APISpark extension of Restlet does something like that. See class `org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.introspection.application.ComponentIntrospector` and `org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.introspection.application.ComponentIntrospector`.

Why do you need such feature in your application? Just to be sure to give the right answer ;-)

**Edited**

You can reach a sample application for your use case at the address https://github.com/templth/restlet-stackoverflow/tree/master/restlet/test-restlet-application-manager.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Im trying to come up with an effective way of shutting down the application from the command line. The application is demonized and has a updater that performs a shutdown of the current version and then starts up the new one. `Application.stop()` seems to be the perfect solution but I am trying to establish the best way of obtaining it. Before I go down the road of setting up a shutdown hook from a specific route I wanted to see if it was possible to obtain the `Application` any other way.

Comment: Do you use OSGi or a plain Java application?

Comment: Plain java. I considered OSGi but its a lot of extra work and it is very invasive for the benefits.

Comment: Incidentally I have just tried calling `Application.getCurrent().stop()` but it didn't seem to shutdown the application.

Comment: In fact, to actually "stop" a Restlet application you need to detach it from its corresponding virtual host(s). Calling the method `stop` is just to free some resources.

Comment: With OSGi, you can tie the application to the bundle lifecycle to attach / detach contained application. With plain Java application, you need to do that by hand. I can provide you a simple example if you're interested in...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79761/discussion-between-tarka-and-thierry-templier).

Comment: Hi, I wonder why you need to have access to ApplicationA from ApplicationB? Why don't you gather all your resources into a single application? In addition, are you aware of the riap protocol that allows you to transmit call inside the components between applications (http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/engine/internal-connectors/riap)?

Comment: I uploaded a project for your use case. The link is within the answer (I updated it). Sorry for the delay and hoping this will answer your issue ;-)